# How to remove duplicated rows using two columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, duplicates

I have a data set like below

```
> set.seed(1)
> tmp <- data.frame(household.id = rep(1000, 6), individual.id = rep(1:3, each = 2),
                 age = rep(c(55, 52, 27), each = 2),
                 income = runif(6)*100)

> tmp
  household.id individual.id age   income
1         1000             1  55 26.55087
2         1000             1  55 37.21239
3         1000             2  52 57.28534
4         1000             2  52 90.82078
5         1000             3  27 20.16819
6         1000             3  27 89.83897
```

That is, the individual "1" is the father of the household "1000", "2" is the mother, and "3" is the daughter.
In this case, I want to use only column 1, 3, and 5.

(i.e. I want to remove one of the duplicated rows using household.id and individual.id)

Also, I want make the mother's age, father's age, and daughter's age variables after the above work.
How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you need something like this ?

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

tmp %>%
  mutate(relation = recode(individual.id,  `1` = 'father', 
                           `2` = 'mother', `3` = 'daughter' )) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = relation, values_from = age, 
              id_cols =  household.id, values_fn = first)


#  household.id father mother daughter
#         <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>
#1         1000     55     52       27
```